# Equidistant "Recursive" form to explicit form

Tags: linear-algebra, recursion

Let $$x_i = \frac{x_{i+1}+x_{i-1}}{2} \quad \text{for $i \in \{2,...,k\}$}$$
and $x_0 = 1$, $x_{k+1}=0$

I want to prove that $x_i = 1-\frac{i}{k+1}$

---

I noticed that $$x_i = \frac{x_{i+1}+x_{i-1}}{2}=\frac{\frac{x_{i+2}+x_{i}}{2}+\frac{x_{i}+x_{i-2}}{2}}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow x_i = \frac{x_{i+2}+x_{i-2}}{2}$$

which makes the points equidistant from each other. Visibly, I see this as a linear function if you'd map $(0,x_0),(1,x_2),...$

But I'd still like some tips how to show this in a nice mathematical way.

Comment: Can you rewrite $x_i$ in terms of $x_{i-1}$ and $x_{i-2}$? You can then prove statements about what possible sequences satisfy your "recursion" relation by induction.

Comment: If you want an algorithmic approach, you can find a general solution for the recurrence that you have, which can be rearranged to
$$
x_{i+2} -2x_{i+1} + x_i = 0,
$$
by following the procedure [outlined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients). From there, use $x_0 = 1$ and $x_k = 0$ to solve for the coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly noticing that it is a linear function is helpful. You can then make the Ansatz $x_j = Aj + B$ and solve for the coefficients. Alternatively, if you didn't notice that, this is a linear difference equation and the Ansatz $x_j = z^j$ would allow you to find this as well.

Comment: The Ansatz $x_j = z^j$ clearly isn't of much help in this case

Comment: That is not true. It would give you the constant term. One could make use of the fact that if a linear operator satisfies $Lz = 0$ and $z$ has multiplicity greater than 1, then additional solutions can be found by differentiation. In this case, $z = 1$ is a double root, so $\partial_z |_{z=1} L z^j = 0$ will be another solution. Hence $jz^{j-1} |_{z=1} = j$ is another linearly independent solution. This is analogous from arguments for multiplicity roots in differential equations.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, thanks for clarifying